# How can I show the latest record in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php

Good Day to all,

I'm a newbie PHP programmer, I would like to ask for help or any idea on how can I be able to show the latest record in my PHP MySQL program.

Goal:

only show the record with the latest revision in master table. for example,

```
#################################
id     filename    revision
1      math12       1
2      math12       2
3      science43    1
4      science43    2
5      science43    3
3      logic13      1
4      logic13      2
5      logic13      3
#################################
```

when I fetch all the record, my goal is only the record with the latest version will show.

```
#################################
id     filename    revision
2      math12       2
5      science43    3
5      logic13      3
#################################
```

like this..

can you help me with my problem..

thanks a lot..

What seem to be the problem in this Code??

```
SELECT 
                                imaster_tbl.id,
                                imaster_tbl.die_name,
                                imaster_tbl.part_name,
                                imaster_tbl.drawing_number,
                                imaster_tbl.drawing_part_number,
                                imaster_tbl.sub_letter,
                                imaster_tbl.specs,
                                imaster_tbl.file_path,
                                idrawing_type_tbl.drawing_type,
                                idie_type_tbl.die_type,
                                irevision_tbl.revision,
                                irelay_type_tbl.relay_type  FROM imaster_tbl
                                LEFT JOIN idrawing_type_tbl ON imaster_tbl.drawing_type_id = idrawing_type_tbl.drawing_type_id
                                LEFT JOIN idie_type_tbl ON imaster_tbl.die_type_id = idie_type_tbl.die_type_id
                                LEFT JOIN irelay_type_tbl ON imaster_tbl.relay_type_id = irelay_type_tbl.relay_type_id 
                                LEFT JOIN irevision_tbl ON imaster_tbl.revision_id = irevision_tbl.revision_id 
                                WHERE revision = (SELECT MAX(revision) FROM imaster_tbl WHERE drawing_part_number = drawing_part_number)
```

-martin

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, please take a moment to search the archives first. For example, if you did a search on [`[mysql] get latest record`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+get+latest+record), there are a bunch of existing threads that answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many equivalent ways of writing this query using a subquery, here is one of them:

`select * from table t1 where revision = (select max(revision) from table t2 where t2.filename = t1.filename)`

You could also write it using `ANY`, `ALL`, `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` operators, if you prefer to do it differently.

Comment: thanks a lot Patashu for your quick response.. I'll try it and a will give you feed back later.. thanks again.. :)

Comment: Patashu I already tried your idea but it only shows the max revision. in my case it only shows all records with the highest revision and disregard all the record with only has the revision 2 is the latest.

Comment: @ChocoMartin If you mean 'it only shows rows with revision 3, which is the largest in the table', you have not implemented the same query I have wrote about in my answer. Notice that I use a dependent subquery, e.g. it considers the maximum revision only of rows of the same filename as the outer query is currently considering. So for filenames where the maximum revision is 2, it will be finding 2, if it is 3 3, etc.

Comment: boom!! I already got it.. thanks a lot @Patashu

Comment: @ChocoMartin If your answer is different from anyone else's answer, please post and accept your own answer to make the question useful to future viewers. Otherwise, accept the answer that inspired your solution.

Comment: I also tried the other suggestions, but your answer is the one I need.. thanks for sharing your knowledge. More power to you..

Comment: I have 1 question, what seem to be the problem:

Answer (score 0):

First build a subquery with the key and max revision, then join on it to get the rest of the record:

```sql
SELECT 
  tablename.* 
FROM 
  tablename
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      filename, MAX(revision) AS max_revision 
    FROM 
      tablename 
    GROUP BY 
      filename
  ) AS max_revisions
  ON tablename.filename = max_revisions.tablename
  AND tablename.revision = max_revisions.max_revision
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I always got this error  "#1054 - Unknown column 'max_revision.version' in 'on clause'"

Comment: I only use 1 table sir.. table name:version

Answer (score -1):

Just a simple and clean solution

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id!='' ORDER BY revision DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: That does *not* return the correct result.